# Insert the contents of an asset pipeline-processed javascript file into HTML

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, lazy-loading

With this code:

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'execute_asap' %>`

I can include a script that that links to `execute_asap.js`.

However, to truly execute this script as soon as possible the contents of the script should appear in the HTML document itself so that the client doesn't have to make an additional HTTP request to get the javascript.

Is there any way to accomplish this while still getting the benefits of the asset pipeline and manifest files?

My use case is that I use javascript to lazily load my images and I want to kick off image loading as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar but with a css file. I ended up, making an own method for it in `helper/application_helper.rb`. So I look for the compiled asset and return it minified and `html_safe`.

```rb
def inline_css
  return Rails.application.assets.find_asset('application').to_s unless Rails.env.production?

  File.read([Rails.root,
             'public',
             'assets',
             Rails.application.assets_manifest.files.select { |k, v| k if v['logical_path'] == 'application.css' }
                                                    .sort_by{|k,v| v['mtime']}.last.first].join('/').to_s)
                                                    .gsub(/\r\n|\r|\n|/, '')
end
```

```
<style><%= inline_css.html_safe %></style>
```

It's not the prettiest solution, but that worked for me.

Comment: Oddly `Rails.application.assets_manifest.files` is empty for me in development. Did you have to do something special to get this to work? I set `config.assets.debug = false` but this didn't help either. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes had the same problem. Thought it was just for me, so I removed it from the answer... I update my inital comment with that fix.

Comment: I believe `'application'` in the first line of that method should actually be `'application.css'`. Otherwise you'll also get `application.js` if it exists.